# Why is my nav-bar not taking up the entire container?

Tags: html, css

[The nav-bar isn't a perfect rectangle, nor is it in line with the header image/body container. (This is an image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2azMs.jpg)

I'm just starting out with coding so I'm sorry for using incorrect terminology. Anyway this has been driving me nuts and nothing I'm doing is making it line up properly... I'll link the full code in a pastebin, and post the CSS and HTML for the menu itself here.

```
  <nav class="nav">
  <ul><li>Home</li>
  <li>About
    <ul>
  <a href="about.html"><li>Open Skies</li></a>
      <a href="hippotherapy.html"><li>Our Therapy</li></a>
      <a href="horses.html"><li>Our Horses</li></a>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="photos.html">Photos</a></li>
  <li>Support
        <ul>
      <li>Volunteer</li>
      <li>Donate</li>
        </ul>
   </li>
  <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

ul {
    width: 1004px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px 4px 16px 0;
  list-style: none;
    background-color: #58C84F;
    background-image: url(images/navbar.png);
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0px 0 3px hsla(0,100%,1%,0.48);  
    z-index: 10;
}

ul li {
    width: 159px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -3px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-right: 19px;
    padding-left: 19px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}

ul li:hover {
  background: hsla(129,31%,25%,0.59);
}

ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  background-image: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: hsla(113,33%,19%,1.00);
  top: 60px;
  left: 0;
  width: 199px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

ul li ul li { 
text-align: left;
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
  font-size: 18px;
}

ul li ul li:hover {
    background: hsla(117,41%,25%,1.00) ;
    }

ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

[This is the full code.](http://pastebin.com/QE9EB3gC)

PS: I'm using Dreamweaver CC.

Comment: For the uneven section in your image (bottom circle), change `display: inline-block;` to `display: block;` and add `float: left;` to `#main`

Comment: @AlexWright thank you! doing that actually fixed both problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of your problem is a result of `display: inline-block` and the rest is margin/box-sizing issues.

**Using inline-block**

`display: inline-block;` causes elements to be added to the screen using the same rules as text. This also means that any spaces between these elements in the HTML are used too. There are [a lot of ways](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) to fix this, but I changed the `display: inline-block;` property to `float: left;` (Don't forget a clearfix!)

Next, you need to remove the negative margins you have everywhere. These were mostly added to take care of the issue above and are only going to mess with the rest of the layout as you continue to make changes.

**Box-sizing (optional)**

Lastly, `box-sizing: border-box` allows you to adjust padding and borders without affecting the outer width of a box. That is, `width` is not changing the content box width anymore. Instead, it changes the width of the element up to (and including) the borders. This is an optional step, but I've found that it makes things much easier to calculate since you don't need to add/subtract padding or border widths to make that perfect fit.

```css
body {
    background: #EFF5F9;
}
.heading {
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #71C969;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 0px 0 3px hsla(0,100%,1%,0.48);
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background-image: url(images/titles.png);
}

#header {
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px auto;
    height: 250px;
}

.content {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

ul {
    width: 1000px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #58C84F;
    background-image: url(images/navbar.png);
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0px 0 3px hsla(0,100%,1%,0.48);  
    z-index: 10;
}

/* Clearfix */
ul::after { content: ""; display: block; clear: both; }

ul li {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 200px; /* There are 5 nav elements, so this is 1/5 of parent width (1000px) */
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-right: 19px;
    padding-left: 19px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}

ul li:hover {
    background: hsla(129,31%,25%,0.59);
}

ul li ul {
    padding: 0;
    background-image: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: hsla(113,33%,19%,1.00);
    top: 60px;
    left: 0;
    width: 199px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

ul li ul li {
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
    font-size: 18px;
}

ul li ul li:hover {
    background: hsla(117,41%,25%,1.00) ;
}

ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

#container {
    background: #D6F1D4;
    min-height: 1000px;
}

#sidebar-left {
    background: #BAE4B7;
    float: left;
    width: 23%;
    min-height: 1000px;
    text-align: center;
}

#sidebar-right {
    background: #BAE4B7;
    float: right;
    width: 23%;
    min-height: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#sidebar-right img{
    margin-top: 5px;
}

#main {
    background: #D6F1D4;
    min-height: 750px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #061B05;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.text {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #061B05;
}

.q {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #23761C;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: Cambria;
}

#social media img{
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.faderandom {
    position:relative;
    width:500px;
    height:332px;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.faderandom img {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    user-drag: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <header id="header"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/Header.png" width="1000" height="250" alt="Open Skies Therapeutic Riding" draggable="false"/></a></header>
    <nav class="nav">
        <ul><li>Home</li>
            <li>About
                <ul>
                    <a href="about.html"><li>Open Skies</li></a>
                    <a href="hippotherapy.html"><li>Our Therapy</li></a>
                    <a href="horses.html"><li>Our Horses</li></a>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="photos.html">Photos</a></li>
            <li>Support
                <ul>
                    <li>Volunteer</li>
                    <li>Donate</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="container">
        <aside id="sidebar-left"><div class="heading">Follow us</div><br>
            <div id="social media"><a href="malito: openskiesjeddah@gmail.com"><img src="images/email118.png" width="32" height="32" alt=""/></a>
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Open-skies-jeddah-therapeutic-riding-days-321515728200/">
                    <img src="images/facebook29.png" alt="facebook" width="32" height="32" title="facebook"/>
                </a>
            </div>
            <br>
                <div class="heading">Fun Facts</div><br>
                <div class="text">
                    <p>In Islam, teaching children to ride a horse is prescribed, as well as learning to swim and shooting a bow and arrow.</p>
                    In one hour on a horse, the body may get more exercise than it would in one month on a wheelchair.</div><br>

                </aside>
                <div id="main">
                    <script>
                        $(function(){
                        $('.faderandom > :gt(0)').hide();
                        setInterval(function(){
                        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * ($('.faderandom').children().length-1));
                        $('.faderandom > :first-child').appendTo('.faderandom').fadeOut();
                        $('.faderandom > *').eq(rand).prependTo('.faderandom').fadeIn();
                        }, 3000);
                        });
                    </script>
                    <div class="faderandom">
                        <img src="images/index slideshow/index-_0001_judy-on-spotty-horse.jpg.png" width="500" height="332" alt=""/><img src="images/index slideshow/index-_0002_kid-on-spotty-horse.jpg.png" width="500" height="332" alt=""/><img src="images/index slideshow/index-_0003_kid-with-ball.jpg.png" width="500" height="332" alt=""/><img src="images/index slideshow/index-_0004_DSC04409.JPG.png" width="500" height="332" alt=""/><img src="images/index slideshow/index-_0005_DSC04411.JPG.png" width="500" height="332" alt=""/><img src="images/index slideshow/index-_0006_DSC04391.JPG.png" width="500" height="332" alt=""/><img src="images/index slideshow/index-_0007_DSC04392.JPG.png" width="500" height="332" alt=""/><img src="images/index slideshow/index-_0008_DSC00632.JPG.png" width="500" height="332" alt=""/><img src="images/index slideshow/index-_0009_DSC00637.JPG.png" width="500" height="332" alt=""/><img src="images/index slideshow/index-_0010_DSC00641.JPG.png" width="500" height="332" alt=""/><img src="images/index slideshow/index-_0011_DSC05208.JPG.png" width="500" height="332" alt=""/><img src="images/index slideshow/index-_0012_DSC06302.JPG.png" width="500" height="332" alt=""/><img src="images/index slideshow/index-_0013_DSC06324.JPG.png" width="500" height="332" alt=""/><img src="images/index slideshow/index-_0014_Vibrance-2.png" width="500" height="332" alt=""/><img src="images/index slideshow/index-_0015_Vibrance-1.png" width="500" height="332" alt=""/> </div>
                    <br><div class="q">What is Open Skies?</div>
                        <p>We are a non-profit organization that mostly depends on word of mouth to find both riders and volunteers. We are the only facility in the kingdom of Saudi Arabia that provides hippotherapy, which is the practice of using horseback riding as a therapeutic or rehabilitative treatment, especially as a means of improving coordination, balance and strength. </p>
                        <p>Open Skies was founded in 1998 by Mrs. Judy Houry, who is a  registered qualified therapeutic instructor of north American riding for the  handicapped association, a member of the federation of riding for the disabled  international, and of the equine facilitated mental health association.</p>

                        </div>
                    <aside id="sidebar-right">
                        <div class="heading">meet our horses</div>
                        <img src="images/headshots/badr.png" width="180" height="150" alt=""/><br><img src="images/headshots/hilal.png" width="180" height="150" alt=""/><br><img src="images/headshots/im not sure what her name is.png" width="180" height="150" alt=""/><br><img src="images/headshots/malak.png" width="180" height="150" alt=""/><br><img src="images/headshots/nejma.png" width="180" height="150" alt=""/><br><img src="images/headshots/sebastian.png" width="180" height="150" alt=""/> </aside>

                        </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `z-index:99999` and width and height to 100% and `position:relative;display:block`